# Styling in code fences

Tags: bug, code-formatting

I recently supplied an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71353761/2191572) and the two asterisks were causing italics so I kept messing around until I figured out a solution.

Is it expected behavior that regular code fences of triple back-tick and four leading spaces cause this issue?

---

### Problem:

[image]

---

### Tests:

Note: Meta does not exhibit this issue; err, feature?

**triple back-tick** - italics

```
(?<=^.{3})[^ ]*|(?<=\d{4}).*Article
```

**four leading spaces** - italics

```
(?<=^.{3})[^ ]*|(?<=\d{4}).*Article
```

**triple back-tick with language hint** - no italics

```javascript
(?<=^.{3})[^ ]*|(?<=\d{4}).*Article
```

Comment: *"Also to note: when editing the live preview does not experience the symptom"* it does, you just need to give it a few seconds to update the rendering.

Comment: @Tom Noted. I guess I was impatient =)